# How to receive a file upload POST request using gevent on python

Tags: python, gevent

I have currently a small gevent Python application serving HTML files. I would like to be able to upload a small file.

A form is made to send a file to the `/file_upload` path.

What should I do to receive the file on the Python side to save it on disk?

---

Currently I am sending a `200 OK` response:

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """function used to serve files following an http request"""
    path = environ['PATH_INFO'].strip('/') or 'index.html'
    if path == 'file_upload':
        start_response('200 OK',[('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return 'OK'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to get the file contents with `environ['wsgi.input'].read()`

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """function used to serve files following an http request"""
    path = environ['PATH_INFO'].strip('/') or 'index.html'
    if path == 'file_upload':
        data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH','0')))
        f = open('./uploaded_file', 'wb')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
        start_response('200 OK',[('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return 'OK'
```